# Should the duplicate link inserted by the Community user count as an edit regarding votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

I upvoted a question, it later got closed as a duplicate so I wanted to undo my vote and it was locked.

Shouldn't the insertion of that content count as an edit? Or even the act of being closed (as whatever reason)?

Comment: The purpose of voting up is to distinguish "useful and clear" questions, just because a question is a duplicate doesn't make it useless or unclear.  Why do you want to change/remove your vote?

Comment: +1, but not for taking back an vote but a down vote, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates/62893#62893).

Comment: @Andy, because I wanted to move my upvote to the original -- regardless of my reason, should that insertion count?

Comment: I can see what you're saying - the content of the post has changed so maybe it should be an edit.  But It's not really extra content in the sense that the question has changed.  I also agree with devinb's answer - it could be the difference between a post being wiki or not.

Comment: A discussion that can't be reproduced? A feature request that can't be reproduced either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not be considered an edit. Edits are for when users have changed the *content*. When a "duplicate entry" tag is added, it is a note to other users, but the content was still not *edited* by some user.

This also affects whether or not it turns into CW.

But there is really no *advantage* to have it count as an edit, **except** to people who want to change their votes. But votes should be based on the *question* and not the general context.

If you feel that strongly about it, just manually do a null edit, and remove your upvote.

Comment: Indeed! The closing as a duplicate does not affect it turning to CW. Which is likewise a good thing, though unfortunately editing the post post-reopening to remove it *would* count.

Comment: > *But votes should be based on the question and not the general context.* -- I see it like adding an answer, I would not add an answer to the duplicate, but to the original; it's the same with my vote IMO

Comment: @Juan, I know and I sympatize. but the fact that you're doing it right doesn't mean that I would assume the general populace does it the same way.