# Any Pattern in Voting of Duplicates?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, duplicate-questions

I am interested to know if there is a pattern in voting of duplicate questions.

Look at the question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature). It has 33 upvotes.

The same question duplicated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212140/community-accepted-answers-after-a-period-of-time-and-tipping-point) has 9 downvotes.

Keeping aside the facts about the questions being widely separated by time (Interest may have drifted elsewhere) and almost having the exact wording (the original question might have been easily found by searching) is there any recognizable pattern in voting of duplicates?

Edit:

As @random pointed out, there seems to be questions that recommend patterns:
The question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates) and duplicate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135478/should-i-downvote-a-duplicate-question)

So is there any pattern?

Comment: How about pick examples that aren't disagreeable changes to the system

Comment: that's a good idea. I think I will edit the question to is there any votting pattern to duplicate questions, if you can kindly provide an example.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135478/should-i-downvote-a-duplicate-question

Comment: They're not examples, they're states of current behaviour

Comment: Done added, Waiting for answers

Answer (score 4):

I think time does it's part, but also consider the fact that a lot of duplicate questions are 'been there, done that' questions. We have seen them a dozen times, and people keep posting similar questions over and over again.

Some may vote on the actual question, some may vote on the fact it has been discussed a lot of times, or is considered obvious.

Another thing to consider: a post can gain quite some downvotes when it is posted, while in time, people with the same idea and actually find the duplicate, might upvote it instead of reposting. That will bring a positive score to posts first not received so well.